bash environment variables and shell env
I'm implementing builtins env and export in a project recreating bash shell. I have inside my shell copy of envp, t_env **envp Then I modify it.
What is the conceptual difference between
export a and export a=?
Why in first case I can see it with command export and not env?
How to implement this behavior?
At the moment my implementation is to use flag, to distinguish between env and shell variables, but maybe there is a better way?
And why even exists this option, set variable without value?

export a places an entry consisting solely of a in the environment.  The export command with no arguments shows it; the env command only shows environment variables with a name and = — which plain a doesn't have.  If you do b= and then export b, you'll see that export lists b='' and env lists it.

But why even exists this option? It is not just appearance,  isn't it? And as far as I understand after export a a is not in env var, it is hanging somewhere in the middle

In some versions of Bash, you can export functions too (but not the version I'm using).  There's not a lot of point in export a when you've not set a to be a variable, but there's no obvious reason to deny the option, especially when it should, and does, work when you've set a as a variable.  You could consider reporting an error if the variable exported is not assigned a value — but that isn't what Bash does.  The POSIX 2024 specification of export isn't a great deal of help, unfortunately.

I removed the C tag since this question is entirely about and answered by Bash semantics. What language it is being implemented in is irrelevant.

@JonathanLeffler Does export a actually place an entry in the environment? export myvar1 myvar2= myvar3=ok; awk 'BEGIN{ for(e in ENVIRON) if(e~/myvar/) print e"="ENVIRON[e] }' doesn't find myvar1 (and a C program that walks **environ doesn't find it either)

As I understand it doesn't. That's the point.

@jhnc: When I experimented with export a (where a was not a set variable), export listed a (all on its own; no = sign), but there was no evidence of a in the environment.  When I subsequently assigned a=23, then a turned up in the environment; Bash knew it was supposed to be exported.  When I experimented with b=; export b, then export listed b='' and it was present in the environment.  So, the entry reported by export after export a behaved a bit like a placeholder: "if a is defined, then it needs to be exported".

@JonathanLeffler sounds like we are using different definitions of "environment". I'm talking about the structure passed to the child, not bash's internal bookkeeping (I have difficulty following the code but att_exported and att_invisible seem relevant)

@jhnc: yes, we must be. I am not looking at Bash source code.  I'm observing what happens when Bash is run.

This exists for historical reasons.
I believe in the original Bourne Shell, you could not assign the variable at the same time as exporting it. So you had to do it in two steps:
variable=value
export variable

Later on these were combined, so you could write
export variable=value

but the original export without assignment is still allowed for compatibility

You're correct; in 7th Edition Unix, you had to assign and then export variables.  It wasn't until the late 80s that the export var=value notation was supported, and then it took a while for that to spread.  There are systems that are still in use or only recently gone out of use (such as Solaris) where the /bin/sh doesn't allow the combined operation.

export a makes it possible for a to be added to the environment of a child process but nothing is actually added unless the variable has been assigned a (possibly null) value.
testenv(){
    bash -c '
        declare -p myvar0 myvar1 myvar2 myvar3
        unset_or_null(){
            declare -n var=$1
            case ${var-1}/${var:-1}/${var:+1} in
                1/*/*) echo $1 is unset ;;
                */1/*) echo $1 is null ;;
                */*/1) echo $1 is set ;;
            esac
        }
        unset_or_null myvar0
        unset_or_null myvar1
        unset_or_null myvar2
        unset_or_null myvar3
    '
}
export myvar1
export myvar2=
export myvar3=ok
testenv
echo -----
myvar0=
myvar1=
testenv
echo -----
myvar0=ok
myvar1=ok
testenv

bash: line 2: declare: myvar0: not found
bash: line 2: declare: myvar1: not found
declare -x myvar2=""
declare -x myvar3="ok"
myvar0 is unset
myvar1 is unset
myvar2 is null
myvar3 is set
-----
bash: line 2: declare: myvar0: not found
declare -x myvar1=""
declare -x myvar2=""
declare -x myvar3="ok"
myvar0 is unset
myvar1 is null
myvar2 is null
myvar3 is set
-----
bash: line 2: declare: myvar0: not found
declare -x myvar1="ok"
declare -x myvar2=""
declare -x myvar3="ok"
myvar0 is unset
myvar1 is set
myvar2 is null
myvar3 is set

